# No documentation available in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5

When I hit F1 while the cursor marks a classname in the source code, I get the message on the right side of my IDE: "No documentation available." 
How can I fix this?

I run Qt on Linux Mint 17.1 and I'm just getting familiar with Linux :-)

Thank you.

Comment: Any class in particular?

Comment: I have this problem with every class.

Comment: Did you install it from Mint repositories or Qt website?

Comment: I installed the online installer (with all tools and sources) from qt website. Afterwards build-essentials and libgl1-mesa-dev from the terminal

Comment: I get this problem, too. All I have is the _Qt Creator Manual 3.6.0_, but not the classes documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As @WCoder suggested, run:

```
rm -fr ~/.local/share/QtProject* ~/.config/QtProject*
```

In addition, install Qt, the latest version of which is 5.5.1 at the time of writing this post: https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.1/

In Qt Creator, go to Tools → Options → Help → Documentation and add all the *.qch files in ~/Qt5.5.1/Docs/Qt-5.5 and the one in ~/Qt5.5.1/QtWebView/1.1/ (assuming you installed Qt into your home directory, ~/ ).

Answer (score 1):

In case QtCreator was installed from a system repository via `sudo apt install qtcreator` then one will need `sudo apt install qt5-doc` to get IDE's integrated help files.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange problem (freeze after start QtCreator) and I got it fixed after remove the diretory ~/.config/QtProject

May be this is a problem too:  ~/.local/share/QtProject

You can reload the help files with the qtcreator options.